# SQL - Delete duplicates based on timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, timestamp

I have the problem that there is a history table which makes an extract of a table each day and gives it a timestamp. Unfortunatly the data was loaded multiple times each day in the past, which should not be.

It's like:

- timestamp/id
- 13.07.2020 15:01.../123
- 13.07.2020 15:02.../123
- 13.07.2020 15:03.../123
- 14.07.2020 15:01.../123
- 14.07.2020 15:02.../123
- 14.07.2020 15:03.../123

And should be like:

- 13.07.2020 15:01.../123
- 14.07.2020 15:01.../123

I am looking for a way to delete the duplicates based on the first timestamp for each day.

Do you have any ideas to delete the duplicates in this way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend deleting using a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, CONVERT(date, ts_col) ORDER BY ts_col) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1;     -- targets all records per day except for the first one
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunatly this query doesn't consider the id. Only the RowNumber above 1 for each id and each day should be deleted.

Comment: @Bryan Then consider the updated answer which partitions on each date and ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two columns use aggregation:

```
select id, cmin(timestamp) as timestamp
from t
group by id, convert(date, timestamp);
```

If you have many columns and want the complete row, then `row_number()` is probably the best option:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, convert(date, timestamp) order by timestamp) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, there are more columns as in the example. And I want to delete all timestamps except the min

Comment: @Bryan . . . That is why I provided two queries.  I suspected that was what you really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this select to control:

```
select  a.* from yourtable a
inner join
(
    select id,convert(date,[datetime]) [date], MIN([datetime]) [datetime]
    from yourtable
    group by id,convert(date,[datetime])
) b on a.id = b.id and convert(date,a.[datetime]) = b.[date] and a.[datetime] <> b.[datetime]
```

And the delete:

```
delete  a from yourtable a
inner join
(
    select id,convert(date,[datetime]) [date], MIN([datetime]) [datetime]
    from yourtable
    group by id,convert(date,[datetime])
) b on a.id = b.id and convert(date,a.[datetime]) = b.[date] and a.[datetime] <> b.[datetime]
```